# Clarification needed - みたい (みたいな)

Tags: grammar, translation

みたい as in *like* (someone)

If I want to say "I like people *like* that woman", is it enough to simply say: 女性みたいな人が好きです。
Or do I have to specify the "that" part by putting it like this:
あの女性みたいな人が好きです。

Also, is it allowed to use を instead of が here if it ended with a verb? (好き is an adjective if I remember right)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say 「あの女の人みたいな人が好きです」 is probably better if you're want to talk about *that* woman. Otherwise it may not be clear who/what exactly you're talking about. with may depend on the context though. Also, notice that I replaced 女性 with 女の人. みたい is more casual expression (than のよう) and more everyday expression 女の人 seems more suitable and in line with the level of speech.

You cannot use を in this sentence. 女の人 is the subject of the sentence, not an object. 好き is an adjective, not a transitive verb.

Comment: Very insightful! Just what I wanted.

Comment: I don't think it's a very good idea to regard that が as a subject marker and 好き as "likable".
I sometimes see learners indicate the agent of 好き with particle に, resulting a sentence like 私にそれが好き, which doesn't make sense at all. I believe it stems from the idea of "it is likable for me". 
A word that's equivalent to 'likable' is 好ましい, not 好き.

Comment: @user4092 Right, I had doubts too if it explained it well. I removed this bit to not cause confusion.

Comment: There are multiple diagnostics for subjecthood in Japanese.  See [*The Oxford Handbook of Japanese Linguistics, pp.142-145*](http://books.google.com/books?id=u1M1AwAAQBAJ&pg=PA142&lpg=PA142&source=bl&ots=ml3tzGN3X6&sig=LAZk5h0diMrybw_NOFPkr2wLN9c&hl=ja&sa=X&ei=_d5KU6LKG4T4yQG4n4GoCA&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false) for three tests which show that the "nominative object" in 〜が好きだ is not a subject, along with some arguments that it is in fact an object.